# Definitive list of service providers in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix, vs-extensibility, service-provider

VS2010 has made it easy to write extensions via MEF exports and imports.  However, if you want to do anything useful you have to know what service provider(s) you need to implement your super awesoem extension.

Unfortunately, this information is often spread out all over the place, not well documented or both.

What I'd really love to see is a comprehensive list of all service providers that you can import into your VS extension, and what those providers... um, provide.  Has anybody seen something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [list of editor services you can `Import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885243.aspx) (on MSDN).

Also, for reference, here is [the root MSDN doc page for the editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx).

Comment: Your google fu is superior to my style.

Comment: I have the benefit of being an editor dev that knows that the documentation at least exists, though, so it isn't a fair contest :)